# Why does the javascript handler need to be attached in a different function?

Tags: javascript, callback, google-maps-api-3

In the code available here :
https://gist.github.com/1338861

if I would include the code of the function function attachEvent(marker){...}
into the body of the function 
function addResults(json) {...}

like this :

```
    function addResults(json) {
    if (json.results && json.results.length) {
        for (var i = 0, placemark; placemark = json.results[i]; i++) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(placemark.point.latitude, 10),
                    parseFloat(placemark.point.longitude, 10));
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  title : placemark.name,
                  position: pos
                });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                    var text = marker.getTitle();
                showInContentWindow(text);

                profileMarkers.push(marker);                            
        }
    }       
}
```

the result would be that when clicking on any marker from the map, it would be shown in the content window only the information characteristic to the last marker added to profileMarkers array (instead of the information of the marker clicked).

My question is why does the onclick listener for the marker need to be attached in a different function (attachEvent in this context) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you keep changing `marker` to the last one by continuing the loop. Try this:

```
(function(mkr) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){ 
        var text = mkr.getTitle();
        showInContentWindow(text);
        profileMarkers.push(mkr);
    }
})(marker);
```

In the place of the current google.maps.event.addListener code. This will create a closure and effectively "fix" the value of the variable.

Comment: What do you mean with "Because you keep changing marker to the last one by continuing the loop."? The `marker` variable is visible only in the `for (...){...}` scope.

Comment: Yes, and it keeps changing in that scope, until you reach the last one. Using "var" doesn't create a new variable in the current block, it does so in the current closure. In this case, the addResults function.